# On Android how do I display a background image through a elements on the window, including a ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I have android 2.1 project with a ListView in a LinearLayout.  The LinearLayout has a background set to an image:

android:background="@drawable/background"

My intensions are to have the background alway visible through any data populated on the screen.  It works, for the most part but I'm running into a couple quirks.

1) In the emulator the background fills the screen but on my phone it does not.  I can see a tiny part of it at the top when the app starts and more is revealed as items are added to the ListView.  I can see the background behind every row; just not where there isn't a row.  How do I get it to fill the screen, even on my phone?  It's Droid X, if that matters.

2) In the emulator when I hold down the button on a row and move the mouse over other rows the background disappears on the selected rows.  On the phone, this happens too.  How do I always see the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a FrameLayout and add..

1. An ImageView with your background. Use e.g. `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`, so its scaled keeping the aspect ratio (`layout_width` and `layout_height` both set to `fill_parent`)
2. Your ListView (`layout_width` and `layout_height` both set to `fill_parent`)

Wether you see the image behind the list view or not also depends on the list view element you use.

Also set the ListView's attribute `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` (transparent)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you have not set the background property of the `ListView` and its items.

Set the cache colour hint property of the `ListView` to #000000 (blank).

You can either do this in xml using android:cacheColorHint="@color/blank".

Or in your code using `ListView.setCacheColorHint(0)`

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue, I think you should make your listview to fill all the available space on the screen so that it maximizes its height e.g. **android:layout_height="0dp" & android:layout_weight="1"**

For the second issue, You should keep in mind that when ListView's item is focused, it shows its default colour. You can use **selector** on ListItems to make things more clear & better.